# Unable to upload javascript file to joomla 3

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have recently started working with joomla.
While using Direct php plugin, which allows to execute php code from the article itself, I needed to invoke custom javascript.
But, in order to invoke custom javascript, I have to upload the javascript file to joomla, which I am unable to do.

> Everytime, i try, i am getting the following error **This file type is not supported.**

I have tried adding **js , JS** to **Legal Extensions (File Types)**, but it doesn't seem to work.
Attached is the screenshot of **Joomla Media Manager Settings**

[image]

- Joomla Version :- Joomla! 3.5.0-beta6-dev Beta
- Joomla Platform Version :- Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable
- Php :- 5.4
- Db :- postgresql

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what is the editor you are using for joomla (JCE editor allows you to use and run JavaScript right out of the box.

Comment: this article may help http://www.joomlablogger.net/joomla-news/joomla-templates/how-to-easily-add-javascript-snippets-to-joomla

Comment: I tried using JCE editor as well, but even that is giving me similar error message while uploading javascript files.

Comment: why are you trying to upload the java script in the media. if you don't mind me asking

Comment: I just started learning joomla, and just wanted to explore and see if the javascript can be executed from within an article.
Thats why, I just wanted to use an external javascript, which can be invoked by joomla article

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add an external Javascript file Joomla. You can also add it to an article. But first you must upload the external Javascript file. in order to do this you must first go to extensions and select templates. To the left you will see another menu that says Styles and templates,  select templates. then selected template you're working with. On the top you will see a menu item that will says new file, click on it a pop-up window will appear choose upload file  then choose the Js folder. Once you are sure that everything is correct you can click the “upload button”. You can now click close because you are done with it.

Then fallow this link to add external file to article 
[Joomla 3.x: How to add or Link to a external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756219/joomla-3-x-how-to-add-or-link-to-a-external-javascript-file)

Comment: I used Filezilla to upload js and other files directly to the server, and it worked for me.
Thanks for the help.